# Sitecore media conversion tool eating storage space

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-media-library

I have a question regarding the media conversion tool for Sitecore.

With this module you can convert media items between a hard drive location and a Sitecore database, and vice versa. But each time I convert some items it keeps taking additional harddrive space.

So when I convert 3gb to the hard drive it adds an additional 3gb (which seems logic -> 6gb total) but then when I convert them back to the blob format it adds another 3gb (9gb total). Instead of overwriting the previous version in the database.

Is there a way to clean the previous blobs or something? Because now it is using too much hard drive space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to login to `Sitecore shell`, open `Content Panel` application, choose `Database` and run `Clean Up Databases` tool from there. I helped me in some scenarios but I'm not sure if it will work in yours as well.

Comment: Yes. Use "Clean Up Databases", and in some instances you need to follow up with shrinkdb from your SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

Using "Clean Up Databases" should work, but if the size gets too large, as my client's blob table did, the clean up will fail due to either a SQL timeout or because SQL Server uses up all the available locks.

Another solution is to run a script to manually clean up the blobs table.  We had this issue previously and Sitecore support was able to provide us with a script to do so:

```
DECLARE @UsableBlobs table(
    ID uniqueidentifier
    );

I-N-S-E-R-T INTO 
    @UsableBlobs    
S-E-L-E-C-T convert(uniqueidentifier,[Value]) as EmpID from [Fields]
where [Value] != '' 
and (FieldId='{40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC}' or FieldId='{DBBE7D99-1388-4357-BB34-AD71EDF18ED3}') 
D-E-L-E-T-E from [Blobs] 
where [BlobId] not in (S-E-L-E-C-T * from @UsableBlobs)
```

This basically looks for blobs that are still in use and stores them in a temp table.  It them compares the items in this table to the `Blobs` table and deletes the ones that aren't in the temp table.

In our case, even this was bombing out due to the SQL Server locks problem, so I updated the delete statement to be `delete top (x) from [Blobs]` where x is a number you feel is more appropriate.  I started at 1000 and eventually went up to deleting 400,000 records at a time.  (Yes, it was that large)

So try the built-in "Clean Up Databases" option first and failing that, try to run the script to manually clean the table.

Edit note: Sorry, had to change the "insert", "select" and "delete" commands to allow SO to save the entry.